# How to upload the file using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, android-volley, multipartform-data

I want to upload data to backend API that written in ASP.Net. The header is set as `Content-Type: multipart-form-data`, and then I tested image uploading using Postman like this picture below

[image]

It's work and response Json like this.

```
{
    "image": "http://192.168.100.249/api/images/download/2"
}
```

The header that in response is

[image]

Next, I've do it in Android code to build image upload in application. I've implement `MultipartRequest`, which the code like this

```
class MultipartRequest(url: String, errorListener: Response.ErrorListener, listener: Response.Listener<String>, realPath: String) : Request<String>(Method.POST, url, errorListener) {
    private val builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()!!
    private var entity: com.belladati.httpclientandroidlib.HttpEntity? = null

    private val FILE_PART_NAME = "file"

    private var mListener: Response.Listener<String>? = null

    init {
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
        try {
            builder.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, FileBody(File(realPath)))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException")
        }
        builder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        entity = builder.build()

        mListener = listener
    }

    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
        val headers: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()

        headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")

        return headers
    }

    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        try {
            entity!!.writeTo(bos)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream")
        }
        return bos.toByteArray()
    }

    override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
        return "multipart/form-data"
    }

    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse?): Response<String> {
        return Response.success(response!!.data.toString(), cacheEntry)
    }

    override fun deliverResponse(response: String?) {
        mListener!!.onResponse(response)
    }
}
```

with dependency:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
compile group: 'com.belladati', name: 'httpclientandroidlib', version: '4.3.0'
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I've add the permission to access file in device.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Finally, I've write this code to do upload process.

```
val mQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
val imageUploadReq = MultipartRequest(url, Response.ErrorListener { error -> mQueue.stop()},
Response.Listener<String> { response -> mQueue.stop() }, realPath)
mQueue.add(imageUploadReq)
```

,
which `realPath` is the image path like `external/abc.jpg`.

The image file cannot be uploaded, and response is `[B@b3062730`, when I debug. What's wrong I my code. Any correction are welcomed.

Comment: Try changing `FILE_PART_NAME` from "file" to "image" ( as seen from your snapshot of POSTMAN request

Comment: `FILE_PART_NAME` can be any string.